# How to determine if a zip file in the network path is corrupted or not using Python

Tags: python-zipfile, pysmb

I have some zip files copied to a network drive. I'm using pysmb to connect to the network drive. I know the testzip() method of the zipfile library can be used to check whether the given zip file is corrupted or not. It works well when I specify a local path. How can I use it with SMBconnection?